# MySQL 5.5.9 and Hibernate table creation error on TYPE

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring

While trying to recreate my database using Hibernate + Spring, the SQL that get's generated appends `"type=InnoDB"` to the end of each creation statement. This seems to cause problems with my MySQL5.5.9 setup. It produces the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=InnoDB' at line 1

If I manually remove the type=InnoBD and paste the create command in MySQL, it works fine.

Has someone else come across this error? Is it maybe just a MySQL setting that I need to change? I am using the `my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf` template as my `/etc/my.cnf`.

I also know that the `type` syntax has been deprecated by MySQL, and that `engine` should be used (and it does if I manually alter the create statements). Is there any way to configure this in Hibernate?

Thanks

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use `MySQL5InnoDBDialect` instead of `MySQLInnoDBDialect`.

Comment: helpful answer, but what wrong with MySQLInnoDBDialect.

Comment: @yogeshprajapati `MySQLInnoDBDialect` is for MySQL 4.x

Answer (score 5):

Using 'MySQL5InnoDBDialect' works with 5.1 and 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

In Grails:

Change the dialect statement in DataSource.groovy

Example:

Use "dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" instead of "dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"

You can use the same approach for your project i guess.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if you have changed to org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect (e.g. on MariaDB) and still getting the error check whether the table name (or any other in the query) is not a reserved word or existing object name (e.g. 'position').

Answer (score 0):

After adding MySQL5InnoDBDialect, I got same error but with "Engine=InnoDB". So I added MySQL5InnoDBDialect in properties file and removed @Table annotations from model file.

Answer (score 0):

`type` is deprecated, and removed from newest versions. Use `engine=InnoDB`

Answer (score -1):

No meu caso, instalei o MySQL v5.6.20, e ao rodar minha aplicação que usa Hibernate, teve colocar **MySQL5InnoDBDialect**.

Segue o trecho (persistence.xml) da tag properties:

```
<properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/livrariadb" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="****" />

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
</properties>
```

Comment: This is not the Portuguese version of StackOverflow.