# hibernate xml configuration seems not to work

Tags: java, hibernate

I am learning hibernate, and trying to make xml configuration which seems not to work.

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"

"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">87654321</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/protein_tracker</property>

  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">protein_tracker</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
  <mapping resource="com/andrei/User.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` does not work. I get exception: no available table in the database.

**User.hbm.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="com.andrei.User" table="Users">
    <id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="NAME" />
    </property>
    <property name="total" type="int">
        <column name="TOTAL" />
    </property>
    <property name="goal" type="int">
        <column name="GOAL" />
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In the user.hbm.xml I specify that the table is **users**, but the app looks for table **user**, which is exactly the name name of my entity.

**User.class:**

```
@Entity
//@Table(name="users")  
public class User {

@Id
private int id;
private String name;
private int total;
private int goal;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getTotal() {
    return total;
}
public void setTotal(int total) {
    this.total = total;
}
public int getGoal() {
    return goal;
}
public void setGoal(int goal) {
    this.goal = goal;
}

}
```

If I uncomment the `@Table` annotation from the user class, the app looks for the correct (**users**) table. Why the xml configuration is not working?

Bellow you can see the **hibernate helper class**, and my **main()**

**HibernateUtilities.java**

```
public class HibernateUtilities {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

static {
    try {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure();
        conf.addAnnotatedClass(com.andrei.User.class);
        conf.configure();

        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = conf.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        System.out.println("problem creating session factory: " + e);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    User user = new User();
    user.setName("first name");
    user.setGoal(250);

    session.save(user);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().close();

}
```

Here are my questions

1. Why the xml configuration does not work? The table name specified in **user.hbm.xml** is users, but the app looks for table user.
2. Why `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` does not work?

Here are my logs:

> Hibernate: drop table if exists users Dec 26, 2017 4:55:42 PM
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl
>   getIsolatedConnection INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from
>   JdbcConnectionAccess
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@4612b856]
>   for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the
>   Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection
>   will be set into auto-commit mode. Hibernate: create table users (id
>   integer not null, goal integer not null, name varchar(255), total
>   integer not null, primary key (id)) type=MyISAM Dec 26, 2017 4:55:42
>   PM
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl
>   getIsolatedConnection INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from
>   JdbcConnectionAccess
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@74eb909f]
>   for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the
>   Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection
>   will be set into auto-commit mode. Dec 26, 2017 4:55:42 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl
>   handleException WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting
>   command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error
>   executing DDL via JDBC Statement  at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:313)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
>     at com.andrei.HibernateUtilities.(HibernateUtilities.java:21)
>     at com.andrei.Program.main(Program.java:8) Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at
>   line 1    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2480)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2438)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745)     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
>     ... 13 more
>
> Dec 26, 2017 4:55:42 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl
>   applyImportSources INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script
>   'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@2826f61'
>   Hibernate: insert into users (goal, name, total, id) values (?, ?, ?,
>   ?) Dec 26, 2017 4:55:42 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions WARN:
>   SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02 Dec 26, 2017 4:55:42 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions ERROR:
>   Table 'protein_tracker.users' doesn't exist Dec 26, 2017 4:55:42 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
>   INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC
>   statements Dec 26, 2017 4:55:42 PM
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl
>   mapManagedFlushFailure ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush
>   [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute
>   statement] Exception in thread "main"
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute
>   statement     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1443)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3207)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2413)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
>     at com.andrei.Program.main(Program.java:17) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute
>   statement     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3013)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3513)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437)
>     ... 9 more Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'protein_tracker.users' doesn't exist     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
>     ... 18 more

One of the lines above:

```
Hibernate: create table users (id integer not null, goal integer not null, name varchar(255), total integer not null, primary key (id)) type=MyISAM
```

but after this, there is an exception which I don't understand. In mySql, there is no table created.

Thank you very much and a happy new year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, just follow documentation [Hibernate_doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html)

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
    .addClass(com.andrei.User.class)
```

in this case hibernate will be search configuration for this class User.hbm.xml. Pay attention the config files should be placed near declared class.

instead of

```
conf.addAnnotatedClass(com.andrei.User.class);
```

About second question. Where do you situated  the configuration file hibernate.cfg.xml ??

Comment: in the src folder, outside the package. Check please the logs (I have updated the question). I see the line with the create table query, but there is no table in mySql

Comment: Now the problem in sql Dialect - see the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231325/mysql-5-5-9-and-hibernate-table-creation-error-on-type?s=1|243.7588

Answer (score 1):

You should use (or implement) custom NamingStrategy class in order to map classname "User" to tablename "Users. See for details [spring - hibernate 5 naming strategy configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165694/spring-hibernate-5-naming-strategy-configuration)